# NEXUS artifact download and unzip

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I have a requirement to download and unzip artifact from NEXUS to read values in a file. I want to use this as a stage in jenkins pipeline.

Please let me know if anyone has a solution for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends how do you connect to nexus. For example you need to configure credentials in jenkins configuration for nexus and then use `withCredentials` to download your artifact from nexus. Then use `unzip` from pipeline syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I usually user powershell invoke-webrequest to download files from NEXUS repos.

But there are also NEXUS plugins.